# Jest: How to mock and test socket.io events received to handle an audio element (tsx)?

Tags: jestjs, socket.io, ts-jest

I'm beginning with Jest and I would like to test a class named AudioManager which received socket events with a sound to play/handle
Unfortunately, I can't write a good mock to reproduce the socket event.
Can you give me advices to do this please?

Here is the socket connection:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { token, socketIp, socketPort, roomId } from './configClient';

const SOCKET_URL = `http://${socketIp}:${socketPort}`;

//connexion socket server
export const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
    auth: {
        token: token,
        client: {
            id: roomId,
        },
    },
    autoConnect: false,
});
```

Here is the class I want to test:

```
import { socket } from '../socketManager';
import { isNumber } from '../../helpers/isNumber_isString';
import {
    IAudioPlayer,
    IOptions,
    IPlayingReturnData,
    IDataAudioSocket,
} from '../../structures/IAudioplayer';
import { ICallbackFunction } from '../../structures/ISocket';
import * as console from 'node:console';


//Gestion des events socket pour diffusion du son
export class AudioManager {
    players: IAudioPlayer[] = [];

    constructor() {
        socket.on(
            'data',
            (data: IDataAudioSocket, callback: ICallbackFunction) => {
                if (data.action == 'playSound') {
                    console.log('playSound received', data);

                    const src: string = data.filePath;
                    const options: IOptions = data.params;

                    if (!isNumber(data.id) || !src) {
                        callback({
                            responseCode: 105,
                            message: 'Missing data to play audio file ',
                        });
                        console.error(
                            'Missing data to play audio file ',
                            data.id,
                            src,
                        );
                        return;
                    }
                    this.play(
                        data.id,
                        src,
                        options,
                        (data: IPlayingReturnData) => {
                            callback(data);
                        },
                    );
                } else if (data.action == 'stopSound') {
                    console.log('stopSound received', data);
                    if (!isNumber(data.id)) {
                        callback({
                            responseCode: 105,
                            message: 'Missing id to stop audio file ',
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    this.stop(data.id);
                    callback({ responseCode: 0 });
                } else if (data.action == 'resetAudioPlayer') {
                    console.log('reset received');
                    this.reset();
                    callback({ responseCode: 0 });
                } else if (data.action == 'setVolume') {
                    console.log('setVolume received', data);
                    if (!isNumber(data.id) || !data.params) {
                        callback({
                            responseCode: 105,
                            message: 'Missing data to set volume audio file ',
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    this.setVolume(data.id, data.params);
                    callback({ responseCode: 0 });
                }
            },
        );
    }

    play(id: number, src: string, options: IOptions, cb: ICallbackFunction) {
        console.log(src, options);
        if (src.length < 4) return;

        const player = this.players.find((item) => item.id == id);
        let audio: HTMLAudioElement;

        if (player) {
            player.status = 'playing';
            audio = player.audio;
            audio.currentTime = 0;

            if (options.volume) {
                console.log('volume', options.volume);
                audio.volume = options.volume;
            }
            if (options.loop) {
                console.log('loop', options.loop);
                audio.loop = true;
            }
            if (options.startTime) {
                console.log('startTime', options.startTime);
                audio.currentTime = options.startTime;
            }
            if (
                isNumber(options.playingDuration) &&
                options.playingDuration > 0
            ) {
                console.log('playingDuration', options.playingDuration);
                player.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.stop(player.id);
                    this.handleEnded(player.id);
                }, options.playingDuration * 1000);
            }
            if (player.status == 'playing') {
                audio.play();
                cb({ responseCode: 0, audioDuration: audio.duration });
            }
        } else {
            audio = new Audio(
                src + '?' + Math.round(Math.random() * 8999 + 1000),
            ); // Prevents caching

            //si l'audio n'existe pas au path envoyé
            audio.onerror = () => {
                cb({ responseCode: 120, message: 'inexisting sound:' + src });
                console.error('sound not found in: ' + src);
            };

            console.log('new sound find');

            let timeout;
            if (options.volume) {
                console.log('volume', options.volume);
                audio.volume = options.volume;
            }
            if (options.loop) {
                console.log('loop', options.loop);
                audio.loop = true;
            }
            if (options.startTime) {
                console.log('startTime', options.startTime);
                audio.currentTime = options.startTime;
            }
            if (
                isNumber(options.playingDuration) &&
                options.playingDuration > 0
            ) {
                console.log('playingDuration', options.playingDuration);
                timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.stop(id);
                    this.handleEnded(id);
                }, options.playingDuration * 1000);
            }

            const player = {
                id,
                audio: audio,
                timeout: timeout,
                status: 'playing',
            };

            audio.oncanplay = function () {
                if (player.status == 'playing') {
                    audio.play();
                    cb({ responseCode: 0, audioDuration: audio.duration });
                }
            };

            //fonction fléchée pour capture automatiquement le contexte actuel this
            audio.onended = () => {
                this.handleEnded(id);
            };

            this.players.push(player);
        }
    }

    setVolume(id: number, options: IOptions) {
        const player = this.players.find((item) => item.id == id);

        if (player) {
            const previousVolume = player.audio.volume;

            if (options.fade) {
                player.audio.volume = options.volume;
                player.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    player.audio.volume = previousVolume;
                }, options.fade * 1000);
            } else {
                player.audio.volume = options.volume;
            }
        }
    }

    handleEnded(id: number) {
        const player = this.players.find((item) => item.id == id);
        if (player) {
            clearTimeout(player.timeout);
            player.status = 'ended';
        }
        socket.emit('data', { action: 'onAudioEnded', id });
    }

    stop(id: number) {
        const player = this.players.find((item) => item.id == id);
        if (player) {
            player.status = 'paused';
            player.audio.pause();
            clearTimeout(player.timeout);
        }
    }

    reset() {
        this.players.forEach((player) => {
            player.audio.pause();
            player.audio = null;
            clearTimeout(player.timeout);
        });
        this.players = [];
    }
}
```

And here is test file I began to produce:

```
// import soundTest from './mockAudioFileJest';

//mock de la console.log
const consoleMock = { log: jest.fn(), error: jest.fn() };
jest.mock('node:console', () => consoleMock);

//mock de la socket
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
const socketOnDataMock = jest.fn();
const socketMock = new EventEmitter();
socketMock.on('data', socketOnDataMock);

function getSocketMock() {
    return socketMock;
}

// Mock de la fonction io() pour créer une instance de socket
const socketManagerMock = jest.fn(getSocketMock);

jest.mock('../socketManager', () => ({
    get socket() {
        return socketManagerMock;
    },
}));

import { AudioManager } from './AudioManager';
const audioManager = new AudioManager();

/*----------DEBUT DU TEST DE AudioManager-------------*/
describe('[src/core/audioManager/AudioManager]', () => {
    describe('AudioManager', () => {
        // const audioManager = new AudioManager();

        beforeEach(() => {
            // Mock de la fonction io() pour retourner un mock de socket
            socketManagerMock.socket.mockImplementation(getSocketMock);
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            // Réinitialiser le mock avant chaque test
            jest.resetAllMocks();
        });

        //---------test sur le "constructor"---------//

        describe('#constructor()', () => {
            /////appel socket
            it('should subscribe to the socket connection in constructor', () => {
                getSocketMock().emit('data', 'test');
                expect(socketOnDataMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
            });

            /////test "playSound"
            it('should subscribe to the "playSound" event in constructor', async () => {
                /// v1: appel play avec les bons arguments
                const playSoundData = {
                    action: 'playSound',
                    id: 1,
                    // filePath: soundTest,
                    params: {
                        volume: 1,
                    },
                };

                getSocketMock().emit('data', playSoundData, () => {});
                // await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                //   setTimeout(resolve, 200);
                // });
                expect(consoleMock.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
                    'playSound received',
                    playSoundData,
                );
                console.log(audioManager);
            });
        });

        
    });
});
```

I have actually this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBqlW.png)

I don't if it's a good idea to use Event Emitter but I didn't find much doc to mock socket

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).